# SQL - How to determine if host name matches a known alias name

Tags: sql-server

Below is a script I created to determine if the machine executing this code matches to a known server alias.  However, I need to find a way to get this code into a function.  Is there a more standard way of doing this without resorting to CLR?
My reason for asking is that I have a development machine and a production machine.  If I'm running a certain bit of code on the development machine I want to do one thing; if I run it from the production server, I want something else to happen.

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @runtimeHost nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @devServerAlias nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @results table ( [output] bit )

SET @runtimeHost = HOST_NAME()  -- this would resolve to the non-FQDN machine name
SET @devServerAlias = 'serveralias' -- a known non-FQDN alias for what we think is the same machine as @runtimeHost

--original PowerShell script:
--PowerShell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {foreach ($a in ([Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry(\"hostname.domain.com\")).addresslist.ipaddresstostring) { if ($a –eq [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry(\"aliasname.domain.com\").addresslist.ipaddresstostring) { $true } else { $false } }}"
--The PowerShell resolves the IP address(es) and compares to find a match
SET @cmd = 'xp_cmdshell ''PowerShell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {foreach ($a in ([Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry(\"' 
    + @runtimeHost 
    + '.domain.com\")).addresslist.ipaddresstostring) { if($a –eq [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry(\"' 
    + @devServerAlias 
    + '.domain.com\").addresslist.ipaddresstostring) { $true } else { $false } }}"'''

-- Execute the Powershell.  The result comes as two lines, the first being the answer and the second being a NULL entry.
-- Because of this, we will need to store the result in a table
INSERT INTO @results ( [output] )
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd

SELECT TOP 1 [output] from @results
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Firstly, to get this into a function can't you just wrap it in a stored procedure? For the purpose of identifying if a server is a production/dev instance we use a database property. That way the property is connected to the database not the physical host. Lastly, if you really want to use the HOST_NAME can't you just compare it to a known list rather than messing with powershell.

Comment: (1) You can put it in a stored procedure, but you can't call stored procedures from a function, nor can you query a stored procedure.  (2) In the environment I'm running, I'm loading a BI staging warehouse within a third party program (TimeXtender).  The SQL code gets evaluated against the transaction database, so extended database properties aren't going to help.  At this point I'm either going to implement a lookup table or just compare against the HOST_NAME and remember to update the name whenever we do a server update.

Comment: So basically using TimeXtender imposes some constraints? Yes it seems like a lookup table would be your best bet and less likely to break in the long term. We do the same (we have a different schema for all these non DW admin type objects)